# Loop more CPU friendly Js

Tags: javascript, loops

The code will will alert 1 when the text in the element is rendered. (comes from external JSON bit slow to load). I  have it working. The only down side is that it will keep running even when its true.

I would like the loop to keep checking if the text has render every 5 seconds and stop looping when its done.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var text = $('#des1').text().length;
  if (text > 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var e = $("a.urlcouint").length
      for (var t = 0; t < e; t++) {
        var l = document.getElementById("xurl").href;
        var n = l.indexOf("://") > -1 ? l.split("/")[2] : l.split("/")[0];
        n = n.split(":")[0];
        document.getElementById("xurl").innerHTML = n;
        document.getElementById("xurl").setAttribute("id", "xurldone");
      }
    }, 5);
    alert(1);
  } else {
    alert(0);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Please post readable code when asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the clearInterval method

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
// do something here
    // When a condition is met and you want to kill the timeout
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 2000);
```